# Can we assume that matrices on $O(p,q)$ are in block diagonal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

A class mate of mine recently used the following claim:

If $M \in O(p,q)$, then $M$ can be assumed to have blockdiagonal form, i.e.

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} A &0 \\ 0 &B \end{bmatrix}$$

with $A \in O(p), B \in O(q)$, where $O(n)$ denotes the orthogonal group. However, it is not clear to me why we may assume this. Could you please explain this to me?

Here is the definition of $O(p,q)$:

> Let $O(p,q) := \{M \in M_n \mid M^TI_{p,q}M = I_{p,q} \}$, where $I_{p,q} = diag(\underbrace{ 1,\ldots,1}_{\text{$p$ times}}, \underbrace{-1,\ldots,-1}_{\text{$q$ times}})$.

Comment: If $M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ is $p \times p$, $D$ is $q \times q$, then
$$M^\top I_{p,q} M
= \begin{bmatrix} A^\top & C^\top \\ B^\top & D^\top\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I_p \\ & -I_q \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} A^\top A - C^\top C & A^\top B - C^\top D
\\ B^\top A - D^\top C & B^\top B - D^\top D\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I think there may be some argument for why $B=C=0$, but I am not sure.

Comment: This could use a little clarity - do you mean "all matrices in this group are block diagonal", or "for any matrix in this group, there is a basis for which it is block diagonal"? (The former is not possible by dimension-counting - the space of such diagonal matrices is $p^2+q^2$ dimensional, but the dimension of $O(p,q)$ only depends on $p+q$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Consider a parabolic rotation in $O(2,1)$, by an "angle" $\theta$:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix} \quad 1 & \quad -\theta & \quad \theta \quad \\ \quad \theta & \quad 1-\tfrac12\theta^2 & \quad \tfrac12\theta^2 \quad \\ \quad \theta & \quad -\tfrac12\theta^2 & \quad 1+\tfrac12\theta^2 \quad \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that it has an eigenvector ("axis") $v=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\end{bmatrix}^T$, which is a null vector with respect to the indefinite inner product: $v^TI_{2,1}v=0$.

Also, its characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-1)^3$ (regardless of $\theta$), so its only eigenvalue is $1$, and you can calculate the nullspace of $M-1I$ to find that multiples of $v$ are the only eigenvectors when $\theta\neq0$.

If $M$ had a block diagonal form (with respect to some other basis), then any eigenvector would be a combination of eigenvectors in the positive-definite $p$-dimensional subspace and eigenvectors in the negative-definite $q$-dimensional subspace. But $v$ is not such a combination, as there are no positive-definite or negative-definite eigenvectors ($w^TI_{p,q}w>0$ or $<0$ respectively), only null eigenvectors.

Comment: More simply, in $O(1,1)$, $$\begin{bmatrix}\cosh\theta&\sinh\theta\\ \sinh\theta&\cosh\theta\end{bmatrix}$$ does not have the form $$\begin{bmatrix}\pm1&0\\0&\pm1\end{bmatrix}$$ for any basis, when $\theta\neq0$.

Comment: Really that comment should have been the answer.